# Validate email from java database

Tags: java, validation, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I am trying to validate an email before I put it in my database and check if that email already exist in the database.

I have this controller class:

```
package controller;
import model.Account;
import model.accountInterface;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

/**
* A controller. All calls to the model that are executed because of an action
* 
*/
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Stateless
public class Controller {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dataOne")
private EntityManager em; 
private static int workload = 12;
private String salt;
private boolean done = true;
private static String adminpass = "admin";
private String adminPassHashed;

public String Login(String username, String password) { // tar in två strings
     boolean password_verified = false;
    accountInterface account = em.find(Account.class, username);
    if(account == null) {
        //throw new EntityNotFoundException("No such account");
        return "Wrong username or password";
    }
    if(null == account.getPassword() || !account.getPassword().startsWith("$2a$"))
    {
         return "Wrong username or password";
    }
    /*    
    if(!account.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        //throw new EntityNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");
        return "Wrong username or password";
    }*/
    password_verified = BCrypt.checkpw(password, account.getPassword());
    if(password_verified== true){
        return "Done";
    }
     if(password_verified== false){
        return "Wrong username or password";
    }
    return null;

}

public String newAccount(String username, String password,String name,String surname, String ssn,String email) {
    accountInterface account = em.find(Account.class, username);// letar efter  primary key i data bassen med entety manger
   /* accountInterface emailtest = em.getReference(Account.class, username);
    accountInterface account2 = em.find(Account.class, username);
    String test = emailtest.getEmail();
    */
     if (account != null) {
        //throw new EntityNotFoundException("Account already exist");
        return "Account already exist";
    }
    salt=BCrypt.gensalt(workload);
    String hased_password = BCrypt.hashpw(password, salt);
    long b =2;
    account = new Account(username,hased_password,b, name, surname,ssn,email);
    em.persist(account); // persist till databasen 

    return "Done";
}
public List<Account> getAccounts(){
    List<Account> account = em.createQuery("from Account m", Account.class).getResultList();
    return account;
}

public accountInterface getAccount(String name) {
    return em.find(Account.class, name);
}

// Denna metod lägger in admin först i databasen och blir anropad i viewn
public void init() {
     salt=BCrypt.gensalt(workload);
    adminPassHashed= BCrypt.hashpw(adminpass, salt);
    if (done) {
        long a =1;// skickar en 1 för att admin ska vara först in i databasen.

        em.persist(new Account("admin", adminPassHashed,a,"admin","adminson","9205143218","admin@gmail.com"));
        done = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I am sending the account to the database with this:

```
long b =2;
account = new Account(username, password,b, name, surname,ssn,email);
em.persist(account); // persist till databasen
```

and before this I am creating admin first in the database with this method:

```
  public void init() {
     salt=BCrypt.gensalt(workload);
    adminPassHashed= BCrypt.hashpw(adminpass, salt);
    if (done) {
        long a =1;// skickar en 1 för att admin ska vara först in i databasen.

        em.persist(new Account("admin", adminPassHashed,a,"admin","adminson","9205143218","admin@gmail.com"));
        done = false;
    }
   }
 }
```

this is in the xhtml that call the method with the view

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['email']}" />
<h:inputText id ="email" value="#{acct.email}" required="true"/>          
 </p>
 <p>
  <h:commandButton value ="new Account" action ="#{acct.newAccount()}"/>
  </p>
```

This method is in accManager class in the view that gets called from the xhtml when ever the user wants too create a new account. It calls the method newAccount that is in the class controller

```
 public String newAccount() {
    try {
        startConversation();
        transactionFailure = null;
        succes = false;
        admin = false;
        logout = false;
        account = null;
        // ------calls the method newAccount in controller class-----
        result = controller.newAccount(username, password,name, surname, ssn,email); 

        if (result.equals("Done")) {
            account = controller.getAccount(username);
        }
        if (account != null && account.getUsername().equals("admin")) {//man kollar ifall man är admin här 
            admin = true;
        } else if (account != null) {
            succes = true;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleException(e);
    }
    return jsf22Bugfix();
}
```

And finally, here is the relevant part of my entity class Account that is in the model.

```
package model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Account implements Serializable, accountInterface {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

private String username;
@Column(unique=true) //I made so the email is unique in the database
String email; 

 @OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
private Role role_id;

public Role getRole_id() {
    return role_id;
}

public void setRole_id(Role role_id) {
    this.role_id = role_id;
}
 public Account(){

}

public Account(String username, String password, Long id, String name, String surname, String ssn, String email){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.ssn = ssn;
    this.email = email;   
}
  @Override
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

I added this line too the entity class Account

```
   @Column(unique=true) String email;
```

Now when the user enters the same email you get a warning from glassfish server:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The 
statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a 
unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by
```

'SQL180311142954500' defined on 'ACCOUNT'.

Is there a way to try to get that exception shown to the user in web interface but with a different text, example Email already registered?

Comment: Think about what you're doing. If the account is **not null**, you return because an account with the same user name already exists. So, if it doesn't return, it means the account **is null**. So it can't possibly have an email. That will obviously throw a NullPointerException. You need to find if **another** account exists with the same email. Obligatory note: storing passwords in plain text in the database is a huge no-no. Not respecting Java naming conventions is a pretty bad idea, too.

Comment: Thanks you for the comments ! I changed so that the password is hashed when sent too the database and the log in method. In my course we have not yet talked much about security. As for the java naming conventions, i am looking in too it. Is there any area specifically you think that is most needed for me too look in too ?

Comment: Just define a constraint in the DB to force unique email addresses.

Comment: @Robert thank you for the help. So i looked in too it and added this line too my entity class Account  @Column(unique=true) String email; hopefully this makes it so my database only takes unique value. I am wondering tho if there is a way for me too get a validation or error message from when every i dont put in a unique email to my database ?

Comment: You have to parse the underlying SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException to see that it is your constraint causing the issue and then throw your own error/message.  SQL180311142954500 is generated from your unique=true, so you might want to look at defining a named constraint to make it easier to determine which is which. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html